# MediaPlayer continue playing in background even after mediaplayer.pause();

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I am working with MediaPlayer. I want to make an online streaming radio. Now I have this mediaPlayer object(of MediaPlayer), say in fragment 1 and it plays fine when I am on fragment 1, as soon as I go to fragment 2, its still playing but the problem is when I come back to fragment 1 again and then I try to stop it when pressed on an ImageButton through

```
if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

but it doesn't stop and continues to play in background, and when I click to play that audio I hear two audios, i.e new one and the previous one playing in background.

I also used

```
if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

and that also is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you used only a single instance of mediaPlayer?

Comment: yes with mediaPlayer.pause(); I only used one instance, but when I used mediaPlayer.stop(); then I had to create new instance according to documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("media_player_state", isStarted);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

then in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)..

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("media_player_state")){
        isStarted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("media_player_state");
    }
    else {
        isStarted = false;
    }
```

then in button.OnClick()

```
if(isStarted == true) mediaPlayer.stop();
else mediPlayer.play();
```

Comment: I have initialized isStarted = false; globally.  Will this create problem in it?

Comment: no it doesn't, if you don't understand why you need all this stuff, read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: please, don't forget to set the value of isStarted every time the button is clicked... if(isStarted == true{ mediaPlayer.stop();  isStarted = false;} else{mediaPlayer.start(); isStarted = true;}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding additional check onCLick

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a state problem.. when you change fragment you should put the state of the button in onSaveInstantState()! Without saving the state of the button when you came back in the original fragment, the activity of the button cannot know if the button where already pressed before..
You can try to use a boolean variable in order to know if the button is pressed or not and than save this variable into saveInstantState! Than in on create you can check the value of this boolean and set the button in the right state..

Comment: its not about button state. The state of button is perfectly fine. its some mediaPlayer issue. I can't access mediaPlayer instance again when I come back to fragment 1

Comment: Yes I know.. if you save the instance of the media player in a boolean variable.. then in the onCreate you can simply do

If(variable = true)
     MediaPlayer.stop
Else
    MediaPlayer.play

Comment: I have done this. if(isStarted){mediaPlayer.stop();}else{mediaPlayer.play();}. but unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: can u update your answer for savedInstanceState? I don't get you

Comment: Did you save isStarted variable in onSaveInstantState()?? Without this cannot work

Comment: No I didn't use onSavedInstanceState(). can you give a sample code for that I don't understand how to use them